# How to create ByteImage object and pass to pHash library in C#

Tags: c#, imagesharp, phash

I'm using [pHash library](https://github.com/pgrho/phash) to compare images in my app. It works well, however, the library is tightly coupled to platform dependent types, such as *System.Drawing.Bitmap* or *System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource*.

pHash library has few extensions methods `ToLuminanceImage()` which create ByteImage object and pass to pHash. All extensions use `Bitmap` type under the hood.

Official example:

```
var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(fullPathToImage);
IByteImage byteImage = bitmap.ToLuminanceImage();

// I want to create ByteImage here without using platform dependent types like Bitmap

var hash = ImagePhash.ComputeDigest(byteImage);
```

Is there a way to use cross-platform library (like [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) or so) to create ByteImage manually and pass to the pHash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your idea of tight coupling isn't the same as mine... from the project page: "The Shipwreck.Phash accepts only IByteImage interface. The package does not contain any method to load an image. So additional packages provide extension methods to instantiate ByteImage". So it sounds like if you can implement `IByteImage` for whatever type of image you're actually using (e.g. from ImageSharp) you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet. Yes, pHash accepts IByteImage, and library contains few extension methods `ToLuminanceImage()`, the extensions work with `Bitmap` type under the hood. It would be greatly appreciated if you can provide some examples of `IByteImage` implementations for bmp or jpg formats.

Comment: No, I don't have the time to do that - but it's a simple interface, and you can look at the source code for the implementations targeting WPF etc... so I wouldn't expect it to be hard to port those to ImageSharp. I suggest you *try* doing that yourself, and report *specific* difficulties you've faced.